# Kafka multi/two nodes setup with producer and consumer on different server/node

Tags: apache-kafka

I am struggling to set up a multi node Kafka cluster.

To simplify my request, assuming I have two servers/nodes, node1 and node2. node1 has ip 100.100.100.1 and node2 has ip 100.100.100.2. all the configuration will be under the user kafka@node1 and kakfa@node2.

Currently, I can set up the single node, single broker Kafka on either node by following the quick start example: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart.

I can also create simulated log/topic (to simplify, producer is just the written message from the console/terminal) and write to the producer on node1. Such topic can also be consumed on node1 as well, let's naming this topic as logtest.

What I want to achieve is that Kafka on node2 can consume the topic logtest produced on node1. However, I do not know how to start. I could not find a good post to guide how to set up such connection. So that node2 can consume topics/producers from other nodes/servers (in this example is node1).  The ssh login has been setup such that no password is needed between node1 and node2 to copy files in between.

My question is generally how to set up Kafka on two nodes (with content produced on one node and consumed on another one), via command line (.sh files)?

Comment: The name "server.properties" is a bit misleading for people who are new to Kafka. In my understanding, it actually means the property for the broker, and brokers can be set up on one machine or on different machines (with different ips).  It is actually the zookeeper who manages the connection between different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you should never have an even number of Zookeeper servers, start Zookeeper on node1

Set these properties on node1 and start Kafka

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external.lan.ip.here:9092
```

Point node2 `zookeeper.connect` string at node1, give it a different `broker.id`, and start Kafka on it after setting similar listener properties.

You now have a Kafka cluster of 2 nodes and can use `--bootstrap-servers localhost:9092` (also each other's addresses) in shell scripts on either host to create topics, produce and consumer

Repeat to expand the cluster further

Comment: Thank you so much. This answer and the previous one, together help solve the problem that I have been working on for a week.

Answer (score 1):

A multi-broker Kafka cluster is what you are looking for. A mutli-broker cluster has multiple nodes/brokers(Kafka binaries) working in sync as a cluster to provide fault-tolerance and scalability.

**Setting up the cluster:-**

After setting up a basic cluster ( 1 zookeeper node with one kafka-broker) as provided [here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). You need to do the following steps to add another broker to the cluster.

1. Configure the new broker with distinct id.In the new broker server.properties change the broker id to a unique value.
   [image]
2. Adding a new servername it responds to:- [image]
3. Adding the old zookeeper location to the new broker. Cluster below is being run on localhost(broker-0 on port 9092, broker-1 on port 9093, zookeeper on port 2181). (Zookeeper is one deciding how to maintain leadership and keep the cluster serving data)[image]

Start the new broker now,using the new server-properties.

```
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

When the server comes up successfully without failing. We can go ahead and check if the new broker has connected to the cluster successfully via the zookeeper cli.(this is important as zookeeper is the one maintaining leadership and broker aliveness)

```
./zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
```

[image]

As you can see the ids 0,1 show that both the brokers are part of the same cluster.

You now have a 1 zookeeper 2 broker kafka cluster now.

**Creating a topic:-**

Once the cluster is up, we need to create a topic that is spread across the 2 brokers. Each topic has data split into two parts.(partition) and each partition has duplicate copy to prevent data loss (replication-factor)

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2 --topic helloWorld
```

Check how the topic is setup:-

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic helloWorld
```

[image]

Here we can see each partition and their replicas being spread across two kafka brokers.

**Topic Consumption:-**

To start producing use:-

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic helloWorld
```

[image]

To start consuming use:-

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic helloWorld
```

[image]

Notice how I am producing to :9092 (broker-0) but am consuming from :9093 (broker-1).

This shows how the data is being synced internally within brokers. However, for best practices and high availability, always use all the brokers in the `--broker-list` parameter

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. With your answer, I understand how to setup a Kakfa with several brokers on a single machine. Together with OneCricketeer's answer, I can now successfully set a Kafka cluster with 2 nodes/servers (with different ips).  Now I can produce on one node/server and consume the produced information on another node/server.

Comment: Note: you should be using bootstrap servers with kafka-topics script rather than deprecated Zookeeper flag